# Invalid Property Value on background-image

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

```
.up { background-image: url('/design-library/profound_test/images/cab_images/white-arrow-up.png') 50% 50% no-repeat; }
```

This code is giving me an 'invalid property value' in crome (and safari). I'm using the exact same code on another page, working correctly. I cleared my browser cache. If I remove 50% 50% no-repeat it works fine. Adding either of those 2 properties spikes it again to invalid (testing using developer tools).

I ran it through ProCSSor as well to clean it up, so I'm not sure where I'm screwing it up...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yep because the `background-image` property is for the image part only, not the position or repeat properties of the background, use `background`:

```
.up { 
    background: url('/design-library/profound_test/images/cab_images/white-arrow-up.png') 50% 50% no-repeat; 
}
```

Comment: I concur :-) you beat me to the post though! :-)

Comment: No worries, just needed a fresh set of eyes obviously!

Comment: That's what I get for getting up 2 hours early.

Comment: @TomWalters still don't know I was also getting the same error as the above question then tried your solution but getting the same error for this one: ```background: url(../img/showcase.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed/cover;```. I am testing on Firefox.

Answer (score 13):

Chrome* will also throw this warning (and doesn't display the bg image), if you have a blank space between `url` and `(` like:

```
background-image: url ('img/web-bg.png');
                     ^
```

(Which was the reason for me to search and find this question but no answer and then doing trial and error.)

- ... maybe depending on the Chrome version, I assume.

Answer (score 6):

This error also occurs in Chrome when you don't use apostrophes and your file has spaces. Simply change:

```
background-image: url(../img/file with spaces.png);
```

to:

```
background-image: url('../img/file with spaces.png');
```

Comment: That's not an answer to this question, since here the file path is already single-quoted.

Comment: Somehow, this is the only solution here that worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Even if you do everything described above, you may get an "invalid property value" in Firefox. The workaround is to convert:

```
background: url(../img/showcase.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed/cover;
```

into:

```
background: url(../img/showcase.jpg) no-repeat top center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just **delete** `../` and use it as

```css
background: url(img/showcase.jpg) no-repeat top center;
```

Answer (score 0):

We got the same problem in Chrome ("Invalid property value", image not rendered) because the file name contained parentheses

```
background: url(img/showcase(1).jpg)
```

Removing the parentheses just solved the problem. Just in case that you arrive here like me due to the question's title :-)

Chrome Version 111.0.5563.64