# Django template rendering beckground-image

Tags: django, django-templates

My view send to my template one object with this value:

```
http://dominio/rota/id/original/(nome)8.jpg
```

In my templete I have:

```
<div style="background-image: url( ' {{ obj.url }} ' )"></div>
```

When my template is rendered it looks like this:

```
background-image: url(' http://dominio/rota/id/original/(nome)8.jpg ' );
```

Error:

> Invalid property value

This happens because inside the URL there is a ")" that encloses the value of the url ()

How can I solve this?

I tried the following combinations in the template, without success:

```
<div style="background-image: url(  {{ obj.url }}  )"></div>
<div style='background-image: url( " {{ obj.url }} " )'></div>
<div style="background-image: url( ' {{ obj.url }} ' )"></div>
<div style='background-image: url(  {{ obj.url }}  )'></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's because of the parentheses? They should be legal in a URL. Your path also includes spaces before and after it, which is almost certainly an error.

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14378456/4974980

Comment: @JensAstrup, what does that post have to do with anything? The OP here is only trying to set the background image, not position and repeat.

Comment: @Chris I can seed the error in Chrome f12 tool... In the style tab the URL is blue, when it arrives in the ")" it closes the URL and the rest (ignored) of the url goes black ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Replace `"("` with `"%28"` and `")"` with `"%29"`

It works