# Invalid background property

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwcza.png)

I am getting a background image from external CSS to display. When I check in the element inspector it shows me invalid property used.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Inspector will tell you what file and what line in the file.

Comment: Please make your Question title and statement clear

Comment: There is nothing invalid in the code you’ve shown. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: enclose the url in quotes. url("../img/background.jpg"); .

Comment: @priyadarshiswain tried as you say still not working.

Comment: @Aasim This link may help --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378419/invalid-property-value-on-background-image

Comment: @Xufox since am new to stack overflow made a mistake i will post briefly i my next post apologize.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'background', not 'background-image'. I.e.

```
background: url(../img/background.jpg);
```

Comment: Thanks alot finally got it.

Answer (score 0):

You have written background-image:url(..img/background.jpg) this is correct,may be you have inserted a wrong path or may you have leave a space in "background.jpg" file like this.."backgroung      .jpg" While crating th image name..  Check it out..i have leave a large space in image file for ur understanding,there may be one space only

Comment: background: url(../img/background.jpg); i have coded like this.

Comment: Thanks i have leaved a space near in url.