# Why background property is showing invalid?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a background image to my html by using the `background` property but it's showing invalid in my browser. I looked for the error and [found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378419/invalid-property-value-on-background-image) with same problem. Still not able to figure out the problem.

Here is my code of css:

```
#showcase {
  background: url("../img/showcase.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed/cover;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 650px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 6rem; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fixed/cover` part is invalid, try the following:

```
background: url("../img/showcase.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed;
```

the possible options for the `background` property can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Answer (score 0):

You should use only one fixed or cover
    background: url("../img/showcase.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed;